# IE11 not showing selected list when <s:optiontransferselect> is used

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, internet-explorer, struts2

I have an s:optiontrsanferselect for selectedGrps and unselectedGrps.
SelectedGroups list is coming null when few groups are selected from left to right and when form is getting submitted in IE11 but in chrome and mozilla its coming fine. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Below is the code :

```
   <s:optiontransferselect 
    leftTitle="%  
    {getText('authoring.label.Grps.selectOptions.left.title')}"
     rightTitle="%       
     {getText('authoring.label.Grps.selectOptions.right.title')}"  
     label="%   {getText('authoring.label.Grps')}" tooltip="%              
     {getText('authoring.label.Grps.info')}"  id="unSelectedGrps"   
     doubleId="selectedGrps name="groupVO.unSelectedGroupIds"          
     doubleName="groupVO.selectedGroupIds" list="groupVO.availableGrps"
     doubleList="groupVO.selectedGrps" listKey="name"
     listValue="value" listTitle="description"
     doubleListKey="name" doubleListValue="value"
     doubleListTitle="description" multiple="true"
     allowSelectAll="false" allowUpDownOnLeft="false"
     allowUpDownOnRight="false" buttonCssClass="buttonArrow
     btn btn-primary" cssClass="form-control" 
     doubleCssClass="form-control" 
   />
```

Comment: What's the JS console say?

Comment: StrutsUtils is undefined coming

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, like the specific Struts 2 version you're using, what the exact libraries you're deploying, the JSP details (what tag libs, do you have the S2 JS loading, etc).

Comment: I am using Struts 2.3.8 version and taglibs are `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
 uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/wap-tags.tld" prefix="wap"%>`

Comment: Have you put `<s:head>`?

Comment: I tried putting that after importing taglibs but still its coming.

Comment: @AleksandrM you mean `<sj:head>` , or is it changed ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios: `<s:optiontransferselect>` why `sj`? [head template](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/support-2-3/core/src/main/resources/template/simple/head.ftl#L23).

Comment: Oh, right, old stuff :)

Comment: Still its not coming after adding <s:head/>

Answer (score 0):

On page load we were using `$('#selectedGroups option')").attr("selected", "selected")` and due to that selected groups are not coming as selected but when i used `$('#selectedGroups option').prop('selected', true)` 
then its coming fine so i believe `attr("selected", "selected")` for option  doesn't work for IE